# What's a good way to find the difference between two nose tests runs?

Tags: python, unit-testing, matplotlib, nose, nosetests

I am trying to prepare a pull request for my changes to `matplotlib` here: https://github.com/shmuller/matplotlib.git. After merging with upstream/master (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git), I wanted to find out if I broke anything, so I run the test suite (`python tests.py -v -a`) on upstream/master. I get:

```
Ran 4688 tests in 555.109s
FAILED(KNOWNFAIL=330, SKIP=9, errors=197, failures=16)
```

Now on my merged branch:

```
Ran 4682 tests in 555.070s
FAILED(KNOWNFAIL=330, SKIP=9, errors=200, failures=18)
```

Darn! Quite close, but not the same! So I did break something that wasn't broken before. Since there are thousands of tests, and lots of errors and failures to begin with, it does not appear obvious to find out what I broke.

So my question is: What's a good way to find out which tests broke that weren't broken before?

`tests.py` essentially does:

```
import nose
nose.main()
```

so I am hoping for a feature in `nose` that helps me figure out what I broke, but couldn't find anything in the help (`nosetests --help`). I obviously could log and diff the whole output, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the logs to two files, `A` and `B`. Then use a diff tool like [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) or [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)' `M-x ediff` to see the differences.

---

If you have a guess about what test(s) are relevant to the code you changed, then you could run

```
nosetests /path/to/test_file.py
```

Fix the errors relevant to the code you changed, and then see if outputs are identical (by running `diff`).

---

If you run

```
nosetests --with-id
```

then on subsequent runs, adding the `--failed` flag will cause `nosetests` to re-run only the failed tests. That may also help you zero-in on the differences.

```
nosetests --with-id --failed
```

Comment: That's what I had in mind, thanks. I guess I assumed that nose would have a feature to facilitate that.

Comment: Since there are already popular, well-developed tools for comparing text files, I think `nose` might not have felt a need to integrate such a feature into `nosetests`. That goes hand-in-hand with the [Unix "small tools" philosophy](http://luv.asn.au/overheads/prog/philosophy.html).

Comment: OK, the diff file is over 8000 lines long, which is partially due to the fact that the numbering gets out of sync (4688 tests are run in the one case and 4682 in the other). Trying to reduce that with the `--failed` flag now...